# Как пропустить декодирование значения из файла

Tags: php, json, iconv

есть файл:

```
    {
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008c\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00a8\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u009a\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00bb \u00d0\u009a\u00d1\u0083\u00d1\u0088\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0080"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u009c\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u009b\u00d1\u008e\u00d0\u00b1\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b2"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u009c\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u009f\u00d1\u0083\u00d1\u0085"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0090\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00a0\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b9"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0094\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008c\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b0"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008c \u00d0\u0093\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0085"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pavel  Geptner"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0090\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b4\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00a1\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "\u00d0\u0090\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00a0\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b9",
      "timestamp_ms": 1543941856123,
      "content": "https://www.facebook.com/716628253/posts/10157110751043254/",
      "share": {
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/shipachev/posts/10157110751043254"
      },
      "type": "Share"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "\u00d0\u009c\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u009b\u00d1\u008e\u00d0\u00b1\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b2",
      "timestamp_ms": 1543822921939,
      "content": "\u00d0\u00b2\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u00bf\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082, \u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008b\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00b2 \u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u0088\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb \u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0083\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008f yii2, \u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b1\u00d1\u008f\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b0 \u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008f\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u008e\u00d1\u0082 \u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u008b\u00d0\u00b5 \u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0082\u00d1\u008b:\nhttps://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9",
      "share": {
        "link": "https://www.русские-урлы.рф/"
      },
      "type": "Share"
    }
  ],
  "title": "ech",
  "is_still_participant": true,
  "thread_type": "RegularGroup",
  "thread_path": "jg"
}
```

декодирую значения с помощью функции (спасибо за функцию user:245501):

```
public function changeCharset($array)
{
    // декодирование символов
    array_walk_recursive( $array, function(&$item)
    {
        $item = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $item);
    });
    return $array;
}
```

но когда попадается строк типа [https://www.русские-урлы.рф/](https://www.%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BB%D1%8B.%D1%80%D1%84/) возникает ошибка iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string, если использовать //TRANSLIT то символы будут заменены на ?, а если //IGNORE, то на -. а строки с таким типом кодировки нужны, как такого типа строки пропускать, а остальные декодировать?

Comment: Попробуйте перед началом декодирования поставить `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'ru_RU');`

Comment: @Eleferen не помогло.

Comment: А если конвертировать в Windows-1251?

Comment: @Eleferen та же ошибка а если добавить //TRANSLIT то так же '?'

Comment: `"link": "https://www.русские-урлы.рф/"` у вас так в файле и написано? Я имею ввиду, что в json строке используется кириллица?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев да, в некоторых местах они есть.

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev Ваши действия следующие. После считывания содержимого файла в переменную, делаете преобразование всех символов из кодировке UTF-8 в нужную `$json_str = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $json_str);` после уже вызываете функцию

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев спасибо большое, помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо Евгений Николаев (user:245501), это помогло.

```
$json_str = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $json_str);
```